# Django field look up __date is not returning objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

Why field lookup `__date` and `__month` are not returning any objects?

```py
class MembershipPlanSubscription(TimeStampBaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

```
In [3]: objects = MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.all()

In [4]: for object in objects:
   ...:     print(object.end_date)
   ...: 
2024-01-22 13:59:17.110148+00:00
2024-01-22 14:15:11.589769+00:00
2024-12-22 14:18:38.624196+00:00
2024-01-22 14:26:10.841796+00:00
2024-01-22 16:36:57.632614+00:00
2024-01-22 19:07:11.450086+00:00
2024-12-24 05:14:35.206241+00:00
2024-03-29 10:33:52.058009+00:00
2024-03-29 10:34:03.927215+00:00
2024-04-04 02:44:18.295650+00:00
2024-02-06 21:03:26.650677+00:00
2024-02-07 14:32:00.987613+00:00
2024-02-08 04:54:32.838352+00:00
2024-04-17 20:49:07.252812+00:00
2024-04-21 14:17:38.210087+00:00
2024-04-26 05:10:26.413481+00:00
2025-01-28 11:01:15.567712+00:00
2024-03-03 20:51:27.211525+00:00
2024-03-04 17:54:18.230713+00:00
2024-03-05 05:42:49.367263+00:00
2024-03-06 16:58:31.119124+00:00
2025-02-07 15:13:42.036329+00:00
2024-03-08 15:00:09.944520+00:00
2024-03-09 21:22:32.184259+00:00
2024-05-09 23:49:42.019238+00:00
2024-03-11 15:49:48.272387+00:00

In [5]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__date = '2024-01-22')
Out[5]: <QuerySet []>

In [6]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__date = datetime.date(2024, 1, 22))
Out[6]: <QuerySet []>

In [8]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__year='2024')
Out[8]: <QuerySet [<MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (5)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (6)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (7)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (8)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (10)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (11)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (12)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (13)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (14)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (15)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (16)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (17)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (18)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (19)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (20)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (21)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (23)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (24)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (25)>, <MembershipPlanSubscription: MembershipPlanSubscription object (26)>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

In [9]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__month='02')
Out[9]: <QuerySet []>

In [10]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__month='2')
Out[10]: <QuerySet []>

In [11]: MembershipPlanSubscription.objects.filter(end_date__month=2)
Out[11]: <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Are you running a MySQL database?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem: yes, its MariaDB which is mysql clone

Comment: likely you did not load the timezones into the database (correctly): https://www.django-antipatterns.com/troubleshooting/can-not-extract-filter-a-date-time-field-when-time-zones-are-enabled.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem if you use timezones (`USE_TZ = True` in the database), and you work with a database like MySQL that sometimes seems to lose the data about the timezones.

You can (re)load timezone info into the database with:

```
time_zone_transition /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

on a Unix like database, where you might have to change `root` to another user that has access to the timezone tables of the database.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I dont have rights to touch `mysql` database. Is there a any django or python based solution?

Comment: @Alok: no, since the thing is that Django translates this into a query that determines the date based on the timezone, and the database determines the timezone data based on the tables. You can disable `USE_TZ` (set it to `False`), but then of course, it no longers works with timezones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the following logic and see if it fixes your problem (with creating an aware datetime object including your timezone):

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now

datetime_filter=localtime(now()).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, 
microsecond=0, year=2024, month=2, day=12) # Or any dates/times you'd prefer
```

and then use this `datetime_filter` on your queryset:

```
YourModel.objects.filter(end_date__date=datetime_filter)
```

Or

```
YourModel.objects.filter(end_date__month=datetime_filter.month) # Other filters, ETC.
```

If you print the `datetime_filter` you can see that it is an aware `datetime` object (including `timezone`) and you don't have to worry about difference between your current timezone and your `datetime_filter`'s timezone:

Example:

```
print(datetime_filter)
datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Amsterdam'))
```